# In order to post listbox item IDHTTP?

Tags: delphi, for-loop

sorry.. I know little english...

I want to send them all listbox items.

My codes (sent to the first item);

```
var
  i: Integer;
  satir: Integer;
  str: TStringList;
  response: TStringStream;
begin
  str := TStringList.Create;
  Response:= TStringStream.Create('');
  satir := ListBox1.Items.Count;
  try
    str.Clear;
    IdHTTP1.Disconnect;

    str.Add('author='+Edit1.Text+'');
    str.Add('email='+Edit2.Text+'');
    str.Add('url='+Edit3.Text+'');
    str.Add('comment='+Memo1.Text+'');
    str.Add('comment_post_ID='+'1'); // Hidden items. When I delete the error does not.
    for i:= 0 to satir do 
    begin 
      IdHTTP1.Post(ListBox1.Items.strings[i],str,Response);
      IdHTTP1.Disconnect;
      MessageDlg('Ok.', mtinformation,[mbOK],0);
    end;
  except
    on e: exception do 
    begin
      str.Free;
      Response.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If you correct my mistakes I would be happy.

Comment: This can not be corrected or improved without knowing the server side

Comment: Assuming the ListBox does actually contain proper URLs, what is the actual problem being experienced?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, sent only the first row. (Listbox items: site urls.)

Comment: Is there a reason why are you calling `Disconnect` after each post ? And `satir` variable should get value `ListBox1.Items.Count - 1` otherwise you'll get with the index out of bounds.

Comment: @TLama then it turns into the connection. Do not have a different method?

Comment: From a very quick look into the source it seems you should call `Disconnect` only when the post response contains `KEEP-ALIVE`, but even with this I'm not sure; this is question more for @Remy. IMHO you don't need to call it, but I don't want to state something what might be wrong.

Comment: I have to find a different method. I want to post listbox items urls. :( Thanks.

Comment: `TIdHTTP` manages the connection internally for you, so in most cases, it is not necessary to call `Disconnect()` manually. It's not harmful to do it manually, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few typos and leaks in your code.  Try this:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  satir: Integer;
  str: TStringList;
begin
  satir := ListBox1.Items.Count;
  str := TStringList.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Disconnect;

    str.Add('author='+Edit1.Text+'');
    str.Add('email='+Edit2.Text+'');
    str.Add('url='+Edit3.Text+'');
    str.Add('comment='+Memo1.Text+'');
    str.Add('comment_post_ID='+'1'); // forgot it. Hidden item. Could this be the problem?
    for i:= 0 to satir-1 do 
    begin 
      try
        IdHTTP1.Post(ListBox1.Items.Strings[i], str);
        MessageDlg('Ok', mtinformation, [mbOK], 0)
      except
        on E: Exception do
          MessageDlg('Error: ' + E.Message, mtError, [mbOk], 0);
      end;
      IdHTTP1.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally
    str.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: First post: Complate.
2nd post: Error: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: `str.Add('comment_post_ID='+'1');` <- Hidden item. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Without seeing the actual urls you are posting to, it is hard to say for sure. But hidden fields are important to send, as well as making sure fields are encoded properly as well. `TIdHTTP` in the latest version of Indy will do the encoding for you, but older versions did not encode things like spaces and special characters. A `500` reply can be caused by a posted webform that is malformed in some way. If you keep getting errors, use a packet sniffer to compare how a webbrowser posts the webform vs how Indy posts it.

Comment: I still can not find a way to.. :)

Comment: You still haven't provided ANY useful information to diagnose your problems with.